# LocalDate: equals vs isEqual

Tags: java, equals, java-time, localdate, jsr310

`LocalDate` in Java has two similar methods `equals` and `isEqual`.

What's the difference between them? When do they output different results?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)? It explains the difference in detail.

Comment: @HenryTwist, could you explain it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LocalDate.equals`, like most other `equals` method implementations, will always return false if you pass it something other than a `LocalDate`, even if they represent the same day:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().equals(HijrahDate.now())); // false
```

[`ChronoLocalDate.isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) compares whether the two dates are the same day, i.e. the same point on the local time line:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().isEqual(HijrahDate.now())); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

The `equals()` method will give the same result as `isEqual()`, but only if the argument passed is of the same type (in this case, `LocalDate`).

`isEqual()` can be called with a `ChronoLocalDate` (`JapaneseDate`, `ThaiBuddhistDate`...)

```
public boolean isEqual(ChronoLocalDate other)
```

`equals()` will return false if the argument is not a `LocalDate`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj instanceof LocalDate) {
        return compareTo0((LocalDate) obj) == 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### equals() can handle any reference type

There are two good answers. For the sake of completeness I want to make explicit that the observation by Most Needed Rabbit implies that you can pass something that isn’t a `ChronoLocalDate` to `equals()` but not to `isEqual()`. For example:

```
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MAY, 26).equals("2021-05-26"));
```

Output:

> false

This is standard behaviour of the `equals` method in Java.

Trying to use `isEqual()` similarly gives a compile error:

```
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MAY, 26).isEqual("2021-05-26"));
```

> The method isEqual(ChronoLocalDate) in the type LocalDate is not
> applicable for the arguments (String)

Passing a string or yet a different type is not often useful, though.

### equals() tolerates null; isEqual() does not

Possibly a bit more surprisingly the two methods also treat `null` differently.

```
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MAY, 26).equals(null));
```

> false

```
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MAY, 26).isEqual(null));
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException